# get others column value on onItemSelected in Android

Tags: java, android

My Tbl_Driver have 3 columns _id,Driver_Code,Driver_Name

How do i able to get the Driver_Name when the Spinner OnItemSelected, because The Spinner will only show Driver_Code

```
public void DriverDatabaseConn(){
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
try { 
myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
} catch (IOException ioe) { 
throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
}  
try {  
myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
}catch(SQLException sqle){  
throw sqle;  
}

SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
//SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/DB_BusData", null, 0);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tbl_Driver", null);
//=====Add Additional=====
MatrixCursor extras = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", "Driver_Code" , "Driver_Name"});
extras.addRow(new String[] { "-1", "< Select Driver Code >","< Select Driver >" });
//extras.addRow(new String[] { "-2", "Empty Template","BB" });
Cursor[] cursors = { extras, c };
c = new MergeCursor(cursors);
//===========================


startManagingCursor(c);
//create an array to specify which fields we want to display
String[] from = new String[]{"Driver_Code"};
//create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
//create simple cursor adapter
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );


//get reference to our spinner
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.DriverSpin);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(
                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.DriverSpin);
                TextView textView = (TextView)s.getSelectedView();
                String result = textView.getText().toString();
                Log.d(null,"Spinner1: position=" +  result + " id=" + id);
                global.Driver_ID = id;
                global.Driver_Code = result;
                // at here how i can get the Driver_Name column's value at here?
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Log.d(null,"Spinner1: unselected");
            }
        });
//db.close();
//myDbHelper.close(); //cannot close, otherwise after logout the spinner will blank
}
```

DataBaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.abc2;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "DB_BusData";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

/**
  * Constructor
  * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
  * @param context
  */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
  * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
  * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

if(dbExist){
//do nothing - database already exist
}else{

//By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
//of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
this.getReadableDatabase();

try {

copyDataBase();

} catch (IOException e) {

throw new Error("Error copying database");

}
}

}

/**
  * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
  * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
  */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}catch(SQLiteException e){

//database does't exist yet.

}

if(checkDB != null){

checkDB.close();

}

return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
  * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
  * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
  * This is done by transfering bytestream.
  * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

//Open the database
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

if(myDataBase != null)
myDataBase.close();

super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewrite your DatabaseHelpe and a Test Activity:

```
public class DataBaseHelper {
private static final String DB_NAME = "DB_BusData";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tbl_Driver";

private Context context;
private String path;

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private boolean isInitializing = false;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.path = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(this.path)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("database can't be null");
    }
}

public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
    synchronized (this) {
        checkAndCopyDatabase();
        return getDatabaseLocked(false);
    }
}

/**
 * Attention：just support readable database until now
 *
 * @return
 */
public SQLiteDatabase getWriteableDatabase() {
    synchronized (this) {
        checkAndCopyDatabase();
        return getDatabaseLocked(true);
    }
}

private void checkAndCopyDatabase() {
    File file = new File(this.path);
    if (file.exists() && file.length() > 0) {
        Log.d("TAG", "db already exist");
    } else {
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            copyStreamToFile(is, new File(this.path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static final void copyStreamToFile(InputStream inputStream, File file) {
    ensureDir(file);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        quietClose(inputStream);
        quietClose(fos);
    }
}

private static final void ensureDir(File file) {
    if (file != null && (file = file.getParentFile()) != null && !file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
}

private static final void quietClose(final Closeable closeable) {
    if (closeable != null) {
        try {
            closeable.close();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

private SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseLocked(boolean writeable) {
    if (this.database != null) {
        if (!this.database.isOpen()) {
            database = null;
        } else if (!writeable || !database.isReadOnly()) {
            return database;
        }
    }

    if (isInitializing) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("getDatabase called recursively");
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.database;

    try {
        isInitializing = true;
        if (db != null && writeable && db.isReadOnly()) {
            if (db.isOpen()) {
                db.close();
            }
            db = null;
        }
        try {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.path, null,
                    writeable ? SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE : SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.database = db;
        return db;
    } finally {
        isInitializing = false;
        if (db != null && db != database) {
            db.close();
        }
    }
}

public static class Driver implements BaseColumns {
    long id;
    String code;
    String name;

    static final String CODE_CLOMN_NAME = "Driver_Code";
    static final String NAME_CLOMN_Name = "Driver_Name";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public List<Driver> queryAllDriver() {
    List<Driver> drivers = null;

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Driver._ID));
                    final String code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Driver.CODE_CLOMN_NAME));
                    final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Driver.NAME_CLOMN_Name));

                    Driver driver = new Driver();
                    driver.id = id;
                    driver.code = code;
                    driver.name = name;

                    if(drivers == null)
                        drivers = new ArrayList<DataBaseHelper.Driver>();

                    drivers.add(driver);
                } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }

        db.close();
    }

    return drivers;
}
```

}

The DB open and operation code is above, then I write a Test Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
private List<Driver> drivers;
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    new DBTask().execute();
}

class DBTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Driver>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Driver> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DataBaseHelper dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        return dbHelper.queryAllDriver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Driver> result) {
        bindSpinner(result);
    }
}

private void bindSpinner(List<Driver> drivers) {
    this.drivers = drivers != null ? drivers : new ArrayList<DataBaseHelper.Driver>(0);

    ArrayAdapter<Driver> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DataBaseHelper.Driver>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.drivers);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (this.spinner != null && position >= 0 && position < this.drivers.size()) {
        Driver driver = drivers.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, "selected: driver=" + driver.name + ", code=" + driver.code,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}
The Test Activity is works fine for me, I use the database that I simulated. I think you can't store spinner item in database, how many item in spinner? 10? 100 ? 1000?

You can move query data outside DataBaseHelper.java like this:

```
private List<Driver> queryAllDriver() {
    List<Driver> drivers = null;

    DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = db.query(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Driver._ID));
                    final String code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Driver.CODE_CLOMN_NAME));
                    final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Driver.NAME_CLOMN_Name));

                    Driver driver = new Driver();
                    driver.id = id;
                    driver.code = code;
                    driver.name = name;

                    if(drivers == null)
                        drivers = new ArrayList<DataBaseHelper.Driver>();

                    drivers.add(driver);
                } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }

        db.close();
    }

    return drivers;
}
```

Comment: i m newbie, u should provide more detail coding?

Comment: You Database not correct created, you can see how to use SQLiteOpenHelper to create database and handle db operations. You need to lean basic knowledge about android.

Comment: Can you paste DataBaseHelper.java? If you use SQLiteOpenHelper, you needn't call createDataBase, just create at SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate.

Comment: You can test the code, and I write the method queryAllDriver, you can bind the result with BaseAdapter, I recommend you do the db opreation in asynchronous thread.

Comment: so how i connect database? and how i bind the Spinner with Driver? please provide detail

Comment: I can get anything about driver with the above code, make sure the driver class's toString return the name which show in spinner item.

Comment: this method is use for bind into Spinner, i can't understand how to if i want to read the data with cursor and while (c.moveToNext()) { } like this.

Comment: Then you may to lean how to use Cursor. Cursor is likes an array, contains many items of data, cursor.moveToNext() to check if cursor has more data and move the cursor to the next item.

Comment: cursor can use ur DataBasehelper.java to connect?

Comment: What do you mean? Cursor is just a query result, you can query at every where if you hold DataBaseHelper object instance.

Comment: just make a example how to connect use cursor with your above DatabaseHelper.java . just show me then i will understand

Comment: I have writed it already, you can write the query code outside DataBaseHelper.java, like this:

Comment: if i store  `queryAllDriver() ` function at FuntionClass.java then `DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);` this line will get error. why?

Comment: because u said `You can move query data outside DataBaseHelper.java like this:` so, i can use the Databasehelp outside . why get the error

Comment: DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(this); your's "this" is not a Context instance, is FuntionClass instance, you must transmit a Context like Activity, Application.

Comment: _id must be integer ?
`final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Driver._ID));` can i change this to another column become id ? change at this code. right?